# atomic operations on a variable which is in OpenMP reduction clause

Tags: c++, openmp, atomic

I have a following piece of code. Its idea is very simple. There are billions of events in my full program and I need to count some of them not using *long int* type. So, I have to use 2 *int* numbers *HIT* and *COUNT* istead of 1 *int* number because there will be an overflow of 1 *int* variable (very big loop count).

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <limits>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int N=1000000000;
long int K=20*N;
int HIT=0;
int COUNT=0;
long int MAX=std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  auto begin=std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  for(long int i=0; i<K; ++i)
  {
    ++HIT;
    if(HIT == MAX)
    {
      ++COUNT;
      HIT=0;
      cout<<"COUNT="<<COUNT<<endl;
    }
  }
  auto end=std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  cout<<"HIT="<<HIT<<endl;
  cout<<"COUNT="<<COUNT<<endl;

  const long int Total = HIT+COUNT*MAX;
  cout<<"Total="<<Total<<" MAX="<<MAX<<endl;
  if(Total==K) cout<<"Total == K"<<endl;
  else         cout<<"Total != K"<<endl;
  auto elapsed_ms=std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end-begin);
  std::cout<<"time="<<elapsed_ms.count()<<" ms"<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The code works properly in 1 thread and gives the following output:

```
COUNT=1
COUNT=2
COUNT=3
COUNT=4
COUNT=5
COUNT=6
COUNT=7
COUNT=8
COUNT=9
HIT=672647177
COUNT=9
Total=20000000000 MAX=2147483647
Total == K
time=30971 ms
```

I need to have it working in parallel using OpenMP not using mutexes or some functions connected with compiler implementation, if possible.  But when I modify it as:

```
#pragma omp parallel for simd reduction(+:HIT,COUNT)
  for(long int i=0; i<K; ++i)
```

the output is the following:

```
HIT=20000000000
COUNT=0
Total=20000000000 MAX=2147483647
Total == K
time=2771 ms
```

Finally, when I modify the code as:

```
#pragma omp parallel for simd reduction(+:HIT,COUNT)
for(long int i=0; i<K; ++i)
{
  ++HIT;
  if(HIT == MAX)
  {
    ++COUNT;
  #pragma omp atomic write
    HIT=0;
    cout<<"COUNT="<<COUNT<<endl;
  }
}
```

the output is:

```
COUNT=1
COUNT=1
COUNT=1
COUNT=1
COUNT=1
COUNT=1
COUNT=1
COUNT=1
HIT=2820130824
COUNT=8
Total=20000000000 MAX=2147483647
Total == K
time=4232 ms
```

Could anyone be so kind to explain me what is going on and why the output is so much different?

I need to get the code properly working in parallel using OpenMP, so how to properly do it?

Is

```
#pragma omp atomic write
```

correct or should I write

```
#pragma omp atomic update?
```

Is it possible to write *atomic* operations on the values which already are in OpenMP *reduction* clause?

Use Intel C++ 2019 compiler.

g++ does not allow to use *simd* in

```
#pragma omp parallel for simd reduction(+:HIT,COUNT)
```

and if to drop *simd*, the code works incorrectly using g++.

Comment: I'm guessing that since each parallel thread has its own `HIT` variable (initially zero), and handles a subset of the entire range (K / the number of threads), your condition `HIT == MAX` doesn't occur. You probably wouldn't have this issue if you checked `((i + 1) % MAX) == 0` instead. BTW, your code does compile with simd on GCC 10.1.

Comment: Each thread has its own copy of  HIT and COUNT variables (the are private for #pragma om parallel for clause). That is why all the lines are COUNT=1 in the last case. But, finally, COUNT=8 instead of COUNT=9 for the sequential code. Why?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't undestand why to use ((i+1)%MAX)==0 is better. And I can't use this in my real code. This is only a small reproducing example. In the real code I should handle variables similar to HIT and COUNT.

Comment: I have an older version GCC  5.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `+` reduction won't work for two integers that aren't exactly summed independently, but since OpenMP 4.0 you can declare your own reductions. All you need to do is abstract the two parts of the counter in a `class` (or `struct`) and define a function that sums such objects. In the example below, an overloaded compound assignment operator (`+=`) is used:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

const long int MAX = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
const long int K = MAX + 20L;

class large_count {
   int count, hit;
public:
   large_count() : count(0), hit(0) {}

   // Prefix increment operator
   large_count& operator++() {
      hit++;
      if (hit == MAX) {
         hit = 0;
         count++;
      }
      return *this;
   }

   // Compound assignment operator
   large_count& operator+=(const large_count& other) {
      count += other.count;
      long int sum_hit = (long)hit + other.hit;
      if (sum_hit >= MAX) {
         count++;
         hit = sum_hit - MAX;
      }
      else
         hit = sum_hit;
      return *this;
   }

   long total() const { return hit + count * MAX; }
};

#pragma omp declare reduction (large_sum : large_count : omp_out += omp_in)

int main() {
   large_count cnt;
   double t = -omp_get_wtime();
   #pragma omp parallel for reduction(large_sum : cnt)
   for (long int i = 0; i < K; i++)
      ++cnt;
   t += omp_get_wtime();
   cout << (cnt.total() == K ? "YES" : "NO") << endl;
   cout << t << " s" << endl;
}
```

The custom reduction is declared using:

```
#pragma omp declare reduction (large_sum : large_count : omp_out += omp_in)
```

There are three parts of the declaration:

- `large_sum` - this is the name given to the custom reduction operation
- `large_count` - this is type that the reduction operates on
- `omp_out += omp_in` - this is the combiner expression. `omp_out` and `omp_in` are special pseudo-variables provided by the OpenMP runtime. They are both of type `large_count`. The combiner expression has to combine the two values and update the value of `omp_out`.

Sample output:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
...
$ g++ -std=c++11 -fopenmp -o cnt cnt.cc
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./cnt
YES
9.39628 s
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=3 ./cnt
YES
3.79765 s
```

Comment: Where to find information about imp_out and omp_in and how to use them?

Comment: In the [OpenMP specification](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu107.html). Mind that the linked specification is OpenMP 5.0 and your version of GCC supports OpenMP 4.0. There isn't a convenient HTML version of the latter, but the PDF is [here](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf). Consult section 2.14.3.6.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from each thread having its own copy of `HIT` and `COUNT`. Many of the threads will end with large values in `HIT`. These are aggregated due to the OpenMP reduce clause when the loop ends, resulting in multiple "overflows" of `HIT`.

The simple fix for the OpenMP implementation of the code as shown is to include

```
COUNT += HIT / MAX;
HIT %= MAX;
```

right after the loop ends.

The atomic write directive is a red herring. It changes the timing of the loops, resulting in more threads reaching the overflow limit.

From your problem description, it sounds like the actual `HIT` in your code is an `int`, not a `long int`. This is trickier to resolve, as the multiple overflows cannot be counted using the simple division above because you don't have the precision to fully count everything. You should also consider using `unsigned` instead of the signed `int` type as this can delay overflow problems and, in the event of overflow, avoids the Undefined Behavior you get when a signed value overflows.

Possible solutions include:

1. Using single `MAX` and `COUNT` variables and a mutex protected code block to do the non-atomic increase of the two values.
2. Use single `MAX` and `COUNT` variables, declared as `std::atomic`, along with `fetch_add` (or possibly `exchange`) to handle the updates. If you use `unsigned` types, you can let `MAX` roll over to 0, and update `COUNT` when the rollover happens.
3. Changing `MAX` to be a smaller number, such that (`nThreads * MAX`) does not exceed the numeric limit.

Comment: Oh, beg Your pardon. Of course, HIT and COUNT are int varaibles. Corrected it in the code above. That is why I can not use  COUNT += HIT / MAX; and HIT %= MAX; after the loop ends because there will be an overflow in int variable HIT.